# How can I do to access to a foreign key in the other side?

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-queryset

I am working a on projects using Django. Here is my `models.py` :

```
class Owner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Cat(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pseudo = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I did that :

`first_owner = Owner.objects.get(id=1)`

And I would like to do something like that

`first_owner.Cat`

to get all the cats from an owner

I know I can do something like that :

`first_cat = Owner.objects.get(id=1)`

`owner = first_cat.owner`

But I would like the reverse operation without using ManyToMany field because every cats has an only owner in my case.

My aim is to do that using only one query.

Comment: So what kind of queryset do you want?

Comment: Do you want to access all foreign keys of `Cat` model from `Owner.objects.get(id=1)`?

Comment: @SunderamDubey yes exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all `Cat` instances from `Owner` instance in the view you can do:

```py
first_owner = get_object_or_404(Owner,id=1)

all_instances = first_owner.cat_set.all()
```

In the template you can do it as:

```html
{% for owner in first_owner.cat_set.all %}
   {{owner.psuedo}}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add `related_name` in your model and use it for get all objects referenced as ForeignKey from the given field like below:

```
class Cat(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
             related_name='cats') #---> you can put whatever related_name you want 
    pseudo = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

and query it like this:

```
first_owner = Owner.objects.get(id=1)
all_instances = first_owner.cats.all()
```

You will get all objects referenced as ForeignKey in your `Cats` model.